# Navigation failed for an unkown reason

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

This is a very unique problem. Hours of googling have yielded no answers. Hopefully someone here can help.

I have a LightSwitch 2013 application that is working very well for an internal ticketing system with inventory / asset management. It uses Windows Authentication (we have over 900 employees who are all end users with the ability to submit a ticket, so Forms Authentication is useless), and has no problem with that. Using code I've picked up from various blogs, it gets the currently logged in username, and displays their name on the Home screen; it also gets the user's permissions, and hides / displays elements of the UI based on those permissions. All of that works great, and has for some time.

Here's where it gets weird - navigating to the application is successful. The Home screen loads with all the expected buttons. I can click on a button to bring up another screen, any other screen, and that works great. When I click the Application Icon in the Navigation menu to go back to Home, it loads the Home screen, and a dialog pops up that says "Navigation failed for an unknown reason" I click Ok, and the dialog comes back. One more OK and it clears, and I can continue to use the application normally.

I've been doing minor bug fixes and I started implementing reporting on another screen, so there haven't been any changes to the Home screen since long before this started. My testing shows that this happens with every screen, even screens I haven't yet added reporting to.

This is the code for my Home screen:

```js
/// <reference path="~/GeneratedArtifacts/viewModel.js" />



myapp.Home.created = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    $.getJSON("../Perms/UserPermissions/", function (data) {
        myapp.permissions = data;
    }).then(function () {

        if (myapp.permissions["LightSwitchApplication:ViewTechOnlyScreens"]) {
            screen.details.displayName = "RCC Help Desk Ticketing & Inventory System";
            screen.ScreenName = screen.details.displayName;
            screen.findContentItem("ShowBrowseTickets").isVisible = true;
            screen.findContentItem("Inventory").isVisible = true;
            screen.findContentItem("Users").isVisible = true;
            screen.findContentItem("EnterTicket").isVisible = true;
            screen.findContentItem("SubmitTicket").isVisible = false;
            screen.findContentItem("EnterTicket1").isVisible = true;
            screen.findContentItem("SubmitTicket1").isVisible = false;
            screen.findContentItem("ShowBrowseMyTickets").isVisible = false;
            screen.findContentItem("ShowBrowseOpenTickets").isVisible = true;
            screen.findContentItem("ShowBrowseKB").isVisible = true;
        } else {
            screen.details.displayName = "RCC Help Desk Ticketing System";
            screen.ScreenName = screen.details.displayName;
            screen.findContentItem("ShowBrowseTickets").isVisible = false;
            screen.findContentItem("Inventory").isVisible = false;
            screen.findContentItem("Users").isVisible = false;
            screen.findContentItem("EnterTicket").isVisible = false;
            screen.findContentItem("SubmitTicket").isVisible = true;
            screen.findContentItem("EnterTicket1").isVisible = false;
            screen.findContentItem("SubmitTicket1").isVisible = true;
            screen.findContentItem("ShowBrowseMyTickets").isVisible = true;
            screen.findContentItem("ShowBrowseOpenTickets").isVisible = false;
            screen.findContentItem("ShowBrowseKB").isVisible = true;
        }

        if (myapp.permissions["LightSwitchApplication:AddDevice"]) {

            screen.findContentItem("ShowAddEditDesktop").isVisible = true;
            screen.findContentItem("ShowAddEditLaptop").isVisible = true;
            screen.findContentItem("ShowAddEditPrinter").isVisible = true;
            screen.findContentItem("ShowAddEditTablet").isVisible = true;
        } else {
            screen.findContentItem("ShowAddEditDesktop").isVisible = false;
            screen.findContentItem("ShowAddEditLaptop").isVisible = false;
            screen.findContentItem("ShowAddEditPrinter").isVisible = false;
            screen.findContentItem("ShowAddEditTablet").isVisible = false;
        }

        screen.findContentItem("ShowAddEditEndUser").isVisible = myapp.permissions["LightSwitchApplication:AddEndUser"];

        screen.findContentItem("ShowAddEditTech").isVisible = myapp.permissions["LightSwitchApplication:AddTech"];

        screen.findContentItem("ShowAddEditDepartment").isVisible = myapp.permissions["LightSwitchApplication:AddDepartment"];

        screen.findContentItem("ShowAddEditDeptHead").isVisible = myapp.permissions["LightSwitchApplication:AddDeptHead"];

        screen.findContentItem("ShowBrowseHelpFiles").isVisible = myapp.permissions["LightSwitchApplication:AddHelpFile"];

        screen.findContentItem("ShowAddEditLocation").isVisible = myapp.permissions["LightSwitchApplication:AddLocation"];

        screen.findContentItem("ShowAddEditKBItem").isVisible = myapp.permissions["LightSwitchApplication:AddKnowledgeBase"];

        screen.findContentItem("ShowAddEditOperatingSystem").isVisible = myapp.permissions["LightSwitchApplication:AddOS"];

        screen.findContentItem("SecurityAdministration").isVisible = myapp.permissions["Microsoft.LightSwitch.Security:SecurityAdministration"];
    });
};

myapp.Home.EnterTicket_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    myapp.showAddTicket(null, {
        beforeShown: function (TicketScreen) {
            var newTicket = new myapp.Ticket();
            TicketScreen.Ticket = newTicket;
            msls.promiseOperation(CallGetUserName).then(function PromiseSuccess(PromiseResult) {
                myapp.activeDataWorkspace.RCCHelpDeskInventoryData.Techs_SingleOrDefault(PromiseResult)
                    .execute()
                    .then(function (result) {
                        newTicket.Tech = result.results[0];
                    });
            });
        }, afterClosed: function (addEditScreen, navigationAction) {
            if (navigationAction === msls.NavigateBackAction.commit) {
                var newTicket = addEditScreen.Ticket;
                myapp.showViewTicket(newTicket, "BrowseOpenTickets");
            }
        }
    });
};

function CallGetUserName(operation) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: {},
        url: 'GetUserName.ashx',
        success: operation.code(function AjaxSuccess(AjaxResult) {
            operation.complete(AjaxResult);
        })
    });
};

myapp.Home.SubmitTicket_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    myapp.showSubmitTicket(null, {
        beforeShown: function (TicketScreen) {
            var newTicket = new myapp.Ticket();
            TicketScreen.Ticket = newTicket;
            msls.promiseOperation(CallGetUserName).then(function PromiseSuccess(PromiseResult) {
                myapp.activeDataWorkspace.RCCHelpDeskInventoryData.EndUsers_SingleOrDefault(PromiseResult)
                    .execute()
                    .then(function (result) {
                        newTicket.EndUser = result.results[0];
                    });
            });
        }, afterClosed: function (addEditScreen, navigationAction) {
            if (navigationAction === msls.NavigateBackAction.commit) {
                myapp.showViewTicket(addEditScreen.Ticket, "BrowseMyTickets");
            }
        }
    });
};

myapp.Home.ShowAddEditDesktop_Tap_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    myapp.showAddEditDesktop(null, {
        beforeShown: function (addEditScreen) {
            addEditScreen.Desktop = new myapp.Desktop();
        },
        afterClosed: function (addEditScreen, navigationAction) {
            if (navigationAction === msls.NavigateBackAction.commit) {
                myapp.showViewDesktop(addEditScreen.Desktop);
            }
        }
    });
};

myapp.Home.ShowAddEditLaptop_Tap_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    myapp.showAddEditLaptop(null, {
        beforeShown: function (addEditScreen) {
            addEditScreen.Laptop = new myapp.Laptop();
        },
        afterClosed: function (addEditScreen, navigationAction) {
            if (navigationAction === msls.NavigateBackAction.commit) {
                myapp.showViewLaptop(addEditScreen.Laptop);
            }
        }
    });
};

myapp.Home.ShowAddEditPrinter_Tap_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    myapp.showAddEditPrinter(null, {
        beforeShown: function (addEditScreen) {
            addEditScreen.Printer = new myapp.Printer();
        },
        afterClosed: function (addEditScreen, navigationAction) {
            if (navigationAction === msls.NavigateBackAction.commit) {
                myapp.showViewPrinter(addEditScreen.Printer);
            }
        }
    });
};
myapp.Home.ShowAddEditTablet_Tap_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    myapp.showAddEditTablet(null, {
        beforeShown: function (addEditScreen) {
            addEditScreen.Tablet = new myapp.Tablet();
        },
        afterClosed: function (addEditScreen, navigationAction) {
            if (navigationAction === msls.NavigateBackAction.commit) {
                myapp.showViewTablet(addEditScreen.Tablet);
            }
        }
    });
};
myapp.Home.ShowAddEditEndUser_Tap_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    myapp.showAddEditEndUser(null, {
        beforeShown: function (addEditScreen) {
            addEditScreen.EndUser = new myapp.EndUser();
        },
        afterClosed: function (addEditScreen, navigationAction) {
            if (navigationAction === msls.NavigateBackAction.commit) {
                myapp.showViewEndUser(addEditScreen.EndUser);
            }
        }
    });
};
myapp.Home.ShowAddEditTech_Tap_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    myapp.showAddEditTech(null, {
        beforeShown: function (addEditScreen) {
            addEditScreen.Tech = new myapp.Tech();
        },
        afterClosed: function (addEditScreen, navigationAction) {
            if (navigationAction === msls.NavigateBackAction.commit) {
                myapp.showViewTech(addEditScreen.Tech);
            }
        }
    });
};
myapp.Home.Tickets_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    // Write code here.
    msls.promiseOperation(CallGetUserName).then(function PromiseSuccess(PromiseResult) {
        myapp.activeDataWorkspace.RCCHelpDeskInventoryData.EndUsers_SingleOrDefault(PromiseResult)
            .execute()
            .then(function (result) {
                $(element).closest("[data-role='page']").find(
                    ".msls-title-area").append(
                    "<div style='color:dimgray;font-size:15px;'>Welcome, " + result.results[0].UserFirstName + " " + result.results[0].UserLastName + "</div>");
            }, function () {
                myapp.activeDataWorkspace.RCCHelpDeskInventoryData.EndUsers.addNew();
                myapp.activeDataWorkspace.RCCHelpDeskInventoryData.saveChanges();
            });
    });

    msls.promiseOperation(CallGetUserName).then(function PromiseSuccess(PromiseResult) {
        myapp.activeDataWorkspace.RCCHelpDeskInventoryData.Techs_SingleOrDefault(PromiseResult)
            .execute()
            .then(function (result) {
            }, function () {
                myapp.activeDataWorkspace.RCCHelpDeskInventoryData.Techs.addNew();
                myapp.activeDataWorkspace.RCCHelpDeskInventoryData.saveChanges();
            });
    });
};

myapp.Home.ShowAddEditDepartment_Tap_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    myapp.showAddEditDepartment(null, {
        beforeShown: function (addEditScreen) {
            addEditScreen.Department = new myapp.Department();
        },
        afterClosed: function (addEditScreen, navigationAction) {
            if (navigationAction === msls.NavigateBackAction.commit) {
                myapp.showViewDepartment(addEditScreen.Department);
            }
        }
    });
};
myapp.Home.ShowAddEditDeptHead_Tap_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    myapp.showAddEditDeptHead(null, {
        beforeShown: function (addEditScreen) {
            addEditScreen.DeptHead = new myapp.DeptHead();
        },
        afterClosed: function (addEditScreen, navigationAction) {
            if (navigationAction === msls.NavigateBackAction.commit) {
                myapp.showViewDeptHead(addEditScreen.DeptHead);
            }
        }
    });
};

myapp.Home.ShowHelp_Tap_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    screen.getHelpFile().then(function (helpfile) {
        myapp.showHelpDialog(helpfile);
    });
};

myapp.Home.ShowAddEditKBItem_Tap_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    myapp.showAddEditKBItem(null, {
        beforeShown: function (addEditScreen) {
            addEditScreen.KnowledgeBase = new myapp.KnowledgeBase();
        },
        afterClosed: function (addEditScreen, navigationAction) {
            if (navigationAction === msls.NavigateBackAction.commit) {
                myapp.showViewKBItem(addEditScreen.KnowledgeBase);
            }
        }
    });
};
myapp.Home.ShowAddEditLocation_Tap_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    myapp.showAddEditLocation(null, {
        beforeShown: function (addEditScreen) {
            addEditScreen.Location = new myapp.Location();
        },
        afterClosed: function (addEditScreen, navigationAction) {
            if (navigationAction === msls.NavigateBackAction.commit) {
                myapp.showViewLocation(addEditScreen.Location);
            }
        }
    });
};
myapp.Home.SecurityAdministration_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    // Write code here.
    $(element).find("div").wrap("<a href='http://myserver/Tickets/desktopclient' target='_blank'></a>");
};
myapp.Home.ShowHelpDialog_Tap_execute = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    screen.getHelpFile().then(function () {
        myapp.showHelpDialog(screen.HelpFile);
    });
};
```

It's a big chunk of code, but most of it is repetitive code to call various screens (there are 53 total in the application).

Comment: Have you tried commenting the code out of the home screen to see if that makes a difference?  If you still get the error, that would eliminate the possibility of this code being the issue.

If you try launching the app without debugging through VS and F12 to debug in the browser, it might break where the error is occurring, that would shed some more light on this.

Comment: Not sure which code you're suggesting I comment out, but I have tried that with everything I could that wasn't necessary to make the program functional. If I comment out too much, permissions don't get processed, and none of the buttons display. I only run it in release config in VS, and the F12 view doesn't show any breaks. It does the same thing in the live application published on the server.

Comment: I meant the code in the created method.  If you comment that out and add one line to always make one of the buttons that navigates to to another screen visible, you could run the app and see if you get the same error.  

Alternatively, if you put a breakpoint in the first line of the created method, does the navigation error come up before or after hitting that breakpoint?